# Ошибка в compass "cannot load such file -- compass-normalize"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ruby, npm, compass

Plumber в консоли выдал ошибку такого рода:

```
LoadError on line ["55"] of /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass-normalize
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Устанавливал,compass-normalize, разными способами с инета, не помогло.

Подскажите как правильно уставновить `compass-normalize` в **ubuntu**

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

```
$ compass -v
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2018 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
```

Comment: Удалить оба гема (compass и compass-normalize) и снова поставить их пробовали?

Comment: Только что удалял compass-normalize и устанавливал обратно, не помогло.Попробую переустановить гем compass

Comment: Переустановил - не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решило проблему команда `sudo gem install compass-normalize`

Comment: Это что за непонятная команда?

Comment: в убунте, обычный инсталл гема, только с правами администратора(sudo)